# AssertionError: Expected view to be called with a URL keyword argument named email

Tags: django-rest-framework

This is how my code is written:

**Custom user model**

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a user with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.password = make_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('The superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('The superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'user'
        verbose_name_plural = 'users'
        ordering = ('email',)
```

**Serializer**

```
class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'email', 'password']
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        return user
```

**`urls.py`**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/v1/accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
]
```

**And**

```
from django.urls import include, path

from . import views

app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.UserViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list', 'post': create'}), name='user-list',),
    path('<str:email>/', views.UserViewSet.as_view({'get': 'retrieve', 'put': 'update'}), name='user-detail',),
]
```

**views.py**

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'email'
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

With the above code when I want to update the password of a user I have to send a `PUT` request to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/<email address>/` with **both** email and new password in the body, which means I have to provide the email address two times (in the URL and in the body).

And if I change the `urls.py` to this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.UserViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list', 'post': 'create', 'put': 'update'}), name='user-list',),
    path('<str:email>/', views.UserViewSet.as_view({'get': 'retrieve'}), name='user-detail',),
]
```

And send the `PUT` request without the email in the URL (but in the body with new password) I get this error:

```
Expected view UserViewSet to be called with a URL keyword argument named "email". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.
```

Is this the expected behaviour or I'm missing something?

Comment: Can you share the `UserViewSet`?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem Sorry I forgot to include it. My post is updated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you want to use the `lookup_field`, you must set a parameter in the path. As I read the source code of the function `get_object` of the class `viewsets.ModelViewSet`, the two fields `lookup_field` and `lookup_url_kwarg` are the same and need path a parameter with the same name.

The error message is the assertion message that checks the path parameter keys and the value is provided for `lookup_field`.

So add the path parameter `email` to the URL path or override the `get_object` in the class `UserViewSet`.

If each user only can change its password (e.g. admin at least won't use this class view to change the users' password) you can use this:

```
def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

but you have to add the permission to check the user is authenticated.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure you have provided a solution here or not?

Comment: The solution is to use ```PATCH``` instead of ```PUT```.

Answer (score -1):

Looks good. It works correctly with the django==3 and lookup_field

Some advices:

- check the application settings. You at least forgot to copy the extra configuration
- reload retrieve method in the view. here you're can play with additional param or **kwargs